# Get Stripe Customer Details in Laravel 5.3 with Cashier 7.0

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments, laravel-5.3, laravel-cashier

In Laravel `5.1` with Cashier `~5.0`, I used to get Stipe Customer details of that user like this:

`$customer = $user->subscription()->getStripeCustomer();`

After updating to Laravel `5.3` with Cashier `~7.0`, I changed the above line in controller to this:

`$customer = $user->subscription('main')->getStripeCustomer();`

Since the update, I am now getting the error:

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2440: 
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getStripeCustomer()
```

How can I get Stripe Customer Details in `Laravel 5.3` with `Cashier ~7.0`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get Stripe Customer with `$user->asStripeCustomer()`

Comment: I tried your suggestion @DamirMiladinov but I am getting a similar error: `BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2440: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::asStripeCustomer()`. Do you know what does the error mean exactly? When I searched the source code of cashier in `cashier/src/SubscriptionBuilder.php` I can see the `getStripeCustomer()` method. So I am not sure why the error is showing and what its saying exactly.

Comment: Hi @DamirMiladinov, you are absolutely right. `$user->asStripeCustomer()` did work. I was wrong when I tried it first. In a haste to try your suggestion, I wrongly had it as `$user->subscription('main')->asStripeCustomer()`. Thats why the method did not work since the relationship was wrong. After re-reading your answer again, I realised how I was wrong. Changing it to `$user->asStripeCustomer()` worked and I was able to get the stripe customer info in an array. Thank you so much. You are such a saviour.

Comment: THANK YOU SIR! could not find it anywhere else